face_recognition is not running even though cmake is in my path
I am trying to install the face_recgonition library in python for a project, but it will not install and shows the following error message. I have cmake installed and it is in my path but neither face_recognition nor dlib itself will install.
I tried adding to cmake to the path and installing VSCode build tools. I asked GPT4 and Gemeni (which did not help at all)
I got this following error message:
Error Message From Installation

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
